# Graduated symbology: How to classify based on two similar values?

Tags: symbology, expression

I originally had two polygon layers (states) which contained the value 'power' per state. I merged those two layers into a new one, so that I can apply a homogenous graduated symbology with a color ramp.

In the new merged layer I now have two columns with two seperate power values in them. One is called 'EE_power_sum' and the other 'Projek_power_sum'.
I really do not know how to apply a graduated symbology with a color ramp for both columns...?
I tried to 'solve' this with an expression with the wildcard% and 'LIKE', but I cannot find a solution on how not to select features in the column, but the attribute field name (of the column) itself?

Comment: Which software are you using?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour] which emphasizes the "no chit-chat" nature of our Focused question/Best answer model. Please [Edit] the Question to provide details on the software in use and your exact procedure, since use of `LIKE` in symbology does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using QGIS, use the following expression which will return the larger one of the values in the two fields and you can use this as input for graduated symbology:

`array_max (array ("EE_power_sum","Projek_power_sum"))`